# How to determine the AC input impedance of the Common Emitter Amplifier

Tags: transistors

I already implement the circuit and it works fine. I apply 1.8 MHz signal. I’m curious about how to calculate the input impedance, knowing only the DC current gain, beta, of the transistor?

I really appreciate all responses.

[image: schematic image 1]

[image: schematic image 2]

Comment: **Many** books have been written about analysis the of such circuits. Search for "common emitter small signal amplifier" and you will find many tutorials and explanations. **Study those**, then come back with a **specific question** if you have any of those. There is **no reason** for us to teach you that what has been described already in many many places.

Comment: Because there's only a 10 Ohm AC emitter resistor, you'll need to first work out the biased quiescent current as the dynamic emitter resistance will probably be on the same order of magnitude. Regardless, you should be able to make a quick approximation from just looking at it. What have you measured? What have you tried to calculate from theory?

Comment: To add to Bimpelrekkie's comment. It is disrespectful to ask us for a solution to a problem without having tried to solve it alone in advance. Our time is as valuable as your's. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably homework without any signs of prior effort to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the respond.  I'm new in this site.

Comment: Thank you for the respond.  I'm new in this site. What I did, actually I need the amplification of a small signal, it works well, I check it on the scope. I also checked the operating point, that the DC collector voltage is about 1/2 of the supply voltage. Regarding the Input Impedance, it does not affect the signal source.  However I wonder if I can calculate the Input Impedance by only knowing the external component value and beta/DC current gain (this one I can measure). The data sheet of the BJT rarely have the h(hie, hfe, hre, hoe) parameters.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f85eHu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$
- Emitter voltage:
  $$\text{V}_\text{E}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\tag3$$

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_7+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_\text{C}+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_{10}=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_{11}\\
\\
\text{I}_9=\text{I}_8+\text{I}_{11}\\
\\
\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_{10}=0
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_4-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_8}\\
\\
\text{I}_9=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_9}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

When applying the set of equations to your circuit, I used Mathematica-code to solve for the unknowns:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{IE == IB + IC, \[Beta] == IC/IB, VE == V1 - V2, 
   I1 + I3 == IB + I2, I2 == I1 + I6, I8 == I7 + I9, I7 == IC + I3, 
   IE == I4 + I5, I10 == I5 + I11, I9 == I8 + I11, I4 + I6 + I10 == 0,
    I1 == (Vin - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V3 - V1)/R3, 
   I4 == (V2)/R4, I5 == (V2 - V5)/R5, I5 == (V5)/R6, 
   I7 == (V4 - V3)/R7, I8 == (Vx - V4)/R8, I9 == (V4)/R9}, {IB, IC, 
   IE, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2, V3, V4, 
   V5}]]
```

Using that, I got the following result:

```
Out[2]={{IB -> -(((R4 + R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  IC -> -(((R4 + R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) β)/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  IE -> ((R4 + R5 + 
        R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
        R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
        R1 R2 R9 Vx) (-1 - β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  I1 -> (1/R1)(-VE + 
     Vin + (R4 (R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I2 -> (R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) Vin (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + 
            R9) VE + ((R4 + R5 + R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
            R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx) (1 + β)))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  I3 -> (R2 (R5 + R6) (R8 R9 + R7 (R8 + R9)) (VE - Vin) β + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx - 
         R2 (R4 + R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) VE - R9 Vx) + (R4 + R5 + 
            R6) (R8 R9 + R7 (R8 + R9)) VE β + 
         R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx β) - 
      R2 R4 (-(R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) β + 
         R5 ((R8 + R9) Vin - R9 Vx) (1 + β) + 
         R6 ((R8 + R9) Vin - R9 Vx) (1 + β)))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  I4 -> -(((R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I5 -> -((R4 (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I6 -> (1/(
   R1 R2))(R1 VE + R2 VE - 
     R2 Vin - ((R1 + R2) R4 (R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I7 -> -((R2 (R4 (R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) Vin - R9 Vx) + 
           R3 (R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) (VE - Vin) β + 
           R4 (R3 (R8 + R9) (VE - Vin) + (R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) Vin - 
                 R9 Vx)) β) + 
        R1 (-R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx + R3 (R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) VE β + 
           R4 (R3 (R8 + R9) VE - (R5 + R6) R9 Vx) β + 
           R2 (R4 + R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) VE - 
              R9 Vx) (1 + β)))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I8 -> (R2 R4 (R5 + R6) (-R9 Vin + (R3 + R7 + R9) Vx) + 
      R2 (-R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 (VE - Vin) - R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vin + 
         R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7 + R9) Vx) β + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7 + R9) Vx - 
         R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R9 VE β + 
         R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7 + R9) Vx β - 
         R2 (R5 + R6) (R9 (VE - Vx) (1 + β) - 
            Vx (R3 + R7 + R7 β)) + 
         R2 R4 (-R9 (VE - Vx) (1 + β) + 
            Vx (R3 + (R5 + R6 + R7) (1 + β)))))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  I9 -> (R2 R4 (R5 + R6) (R8 Vin + (R3 + R7) Vx) + 
      R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 (VE - Vin) + R4 (R5 + R6) R8 Vin + 
         R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx) β + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx + 
         R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 VE β + 
         R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx β + 
         R2 (R5 + R6) (R8 VE (1 + β) + 
            Vx (R3 + R7 + R7 β)) + 
         R2 R4 (R8 VE (1 + β) + 
            Vx (R3 + (R5 + R6 + R7) (1 + β)))))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  I10 -> (1/(
   R1 R2))(-R1 VE - R2 VE + 
     R2 Vin + ((R2 R4 + R1 (R2 + R4)) (R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  I11 -> (R2 (R4 (R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) Vin - R9 Vx) + 
         R3 (R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) (VE - Vin) β + 
         R4 (R3 (R8 + R9) (VE - Vin) + (R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) Vin - 
               R9 Vx)) β) + 
      R1 (-R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx + R3 (R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) VE β + 
         R4 (R3 (R8 + R9) VE - (R5 + R6) R9 Vx) β + 
         R2 (R4 + R5 + R6) ((R8 + R9) VE - 
            R9 Vx) (1 + β)))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) Vin (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + 
              R9) VE + ((R4 + R5 + R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
              R4 (R5 + R6) R9 Vx) (1 + β))))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  V2 -> -((R4 (R5 + 
          R6) (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
          R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  V3 -> ((R2 + R3) VE)/R2 + (R3 (VE - Vin))/
    R1 - ((R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
         R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
         R1 R2 R9 Vx) (R2 R3 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β) + 
         R1 (R2 R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) + R2 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β) + 
            R3 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β))))/(R1 R2 (R2 R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R1 (R4 (R5 + 
               R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
            R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                  R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β))))), 
  V4 -> (R9 (R2 R4 (R5 + R6) (R8 Vin + (R3 + R7) Vx) + 
        R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 (VE - Vin) + R4 (R5 + R6) R8 Vin + 
           R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx) β + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx + 
           R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) R8 VE β + 
           R4 (R5 + R6) (R3 + R7) Vx β + 
           R2 (R5 + R6) (R8 VE (1 + β) + 
              Vx (R3 + R7 + R7 β)) + 
           R2 R4 (R8 VE (1 + β) + 
              Vx (R3 + (R5 + R6 + R7) (1 + β))))))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
         R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
      R1 (R4 (R5 + 
            R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
         R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
               R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                  R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))), 
  V5 -> -((R4 R6 (R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE +
           R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 R9 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R4 (R5 + 
           R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
        R1 (R4 (R5 + 
              R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
           R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                 R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                    R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))))}}
```

Which means that the output voltage \$\text{V}_3\$ is given by:

```
V3 -> ((R2 + R3) VE)/R2 + (R3 (VE - Vin))/
        R1 - ((R1 ((R2 + R3 + R7) R8 + (R2 + R3 + R7 + R8) R9) VE + 
             R2 ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (VE - Vin) - 
             R1 R2 R9 Vx) (R2 R3 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β) + 
             R1 (R2 R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) + R2 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β) + 
                R3 R4 (R5 + R6) (1 + β))))/(R1 R2 (R2 R4 (R5 + 
                R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
             R1 (R4 (R5 + 
                   R6) ((R3 + R7) R8 + (R3 + R7 + R8) R9) (1 + β) + 
                R2 (R3 (R4 + R5 + R6) (R8 + R9) + (R4 (R5 + R6 + R7) R8 + 
                      R4 (R5 + R6 + R7 + R8) R9 + (R5 + 
                        R6) (R7 R8 + (R7 + R8) R9)) (1 + β)))))
```

---

Using your values, with:

1. $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\space\space\space\Longrightarrow\space\space\space\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{s}\cdot\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{10}{\text{s}}\tag6$$
2. $$\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\space\space\space\Longrightarrow\space\space\space\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{\text{s}\cdot\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{10}{\text{s}}\tag7$$
3. $$\text{R}_9=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\space\space\space\Longrightarrow\space\space\space\text{R}_9=\frac{1}{\text{s}\cdot\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{10}{\text{s}}\tag8$$
4. $$\text{V}_\text{in}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[1\cdot\cos\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{9}{5}\cdot10^6\cdot t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{s}}{\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{9}{5}\cdot10^6\right)^2+\text{s}^2}\tag9$$
5. $$\text{V}_\text{x}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[12\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{12}{\text{s}}\tag{10}$$

And I used the assumptions:

1. $$\beta=100\tag{11}$$
2. $$\text{V}_\text{E}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{7}{10}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\tag{12}$$

Solving this, gives:

```
In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{IE == IB + IC, 100 == IC/IB, 
   LaplaceTransform[7/10, t, s] == V1 - V2, I1 + I3 == IB + I2, 
   I2 == I1 + I6, I8 == I7 + I9, I7 == IC + I3, IE == I4 + I5, 
   I10 == I5 + I11, I9 == I8 + I11, I4 + I6 + I10 == 0, 
   I1 == (LaplaceTransform[1*Cos[2*Pi*(9/5)*10^6*t], t, s] - 
       V1)/(1/(s*(1/10))), I2 == (V1)/1000, I3 == (V3 - V1)/2700, 
   I4 == (V2)/220, I5 == (V2 - V5)/(1/(s*(1/10))), I5 == (V5)/10, 
   I7 == (V4 - V3)/1000, I8 == (LaplaceTransform[12, t, s] - V4)/10, 
   I9 == (V4)/(1/(s*(1/10)))}, {IB, IC, IE, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, 
   I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5}]]
    
Out[3]={{IB -> ((1 + 
      23 s) (-12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) + 
      s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
   200 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  IC -> ((1 + 
      23 s) (-12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) + 
      s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
   2 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  IE -> (101 (1 + 
      23 s) (-12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) + 
      s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
   200 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I1 -> (s^2 (-326427 + 2 s (870074 + 1024955 s)) - 
    32400000000000 \[Pi]^2 (339937 + s (2025061 + 1669570 s)))/(
   5 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I2 -> (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (339937 + s (2025061 + 1669570 s)) + 
      s^2 (339937 + 
         s (10268681 + 
            10 s (1813459 + 
               822140 s))))/(200 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I3 -> (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (17432 + 
         s (1797797 + 9893395 s + 8050000 s^2)) + 
      s^2 (17432 + 
         s (1181697 - 
            5 s (488761 + 712220 s))))/(10 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 +
         s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I4 -> (101 (1 + 
      s) (-12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) + 
      s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
   200 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I5 -> -((1111 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 
          70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) - 
       s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
    100 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
       s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s))))), 
  I6 -> (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (1 + 100 s) (339937 + 
         s (2025061 + 1669570 s)) + 
      s^2 (339937 + 
         s (23325761 - 
            10 s (5147133 + 
               7377500 s))))/(200 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I7 -> (s^2 (60947 + s (2722592 + 5 s (2106469 + 1840780 s))) - 
      12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-60947 + 
         s (-1483692 + 
            5 s (4329091 + 
               4347000 s))))/(10 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I8 -> (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (60947 + 
         s (13984717 + 480 s (1296363 + 1027675 s))) + 
      s^2 (60947 + 
         s (15223617 + 
            20 s (32659657 + 
               24664200 s))))/(10 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I9 -> (s^2 (2500205 + 7 s (18361737 + 13830860 s)) + 
    12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (2500205 + s (128779939 + 103003800 s)))/(
   2 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I10 -> (s^2 (-609470 + s (-17556887 + 20 s (733783 + 1564100 s))) - 
      12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (609470 + 
         s (5167887 + 
            20 s (3786367 + 
               3519950 s))))/(100 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  I11 -> (-s^2 (60947 + s (2722592 + 5 s (2106469 + 1840780 s))) + 
      12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-60947 + 
         s (-1483692 + 
            5 s (4329091 + 
               4347000 s))))/(10 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  V1 -> (64800000000000 \[Pi]^2 (339937 + s (2025061 + 1669570 s)) + 
      5 s^2 (339937 + 
         s (10268681 + 
            10 s (1813459 + 822140 s))))/(s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  V2 -> (1111 (1 + 
      s) (-12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) + 
      s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
   10 s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
      s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  V3 -> (5 s^2 (1281265 + 
         s (74080319 - 80 s (1422886 + 2300975 s))) + 
      64800000000000 \[Pi]^2 (1281265 + 
         s (99106099 + 
            100 s (5359129 + 
               4347000 s))))/(s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  V4 -> (5 s^2 (2500205 + 7 s (18361737 + 13830860 s)) + 
      64800000000000 \[Pi]^2 (2500205 + 
         s (128779939 + 103003800 s)))/(s (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
        s^2) (1046831 + s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))), 
  V5 -> -((1111 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (-8703 + 
          70 s (3757 + 3700 s)) - 
       s^2 (8703 + 10 s (10801 + 11100 s))))/(
    10 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
       s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))))}}
```

Your input impedance is than given by:

$$\text{Z}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{I}_1\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag{13}$$

> Using the complex domain, we get (using \$\omega=2\pi\cdot\frac{9}{5}\cdot10^6\$):
>
> $$\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\approx33.0239\space\Omega\tag{14}$$

I used Mathematica again:

```
In[4]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[Abs[(LaplaceTransform[1*Cos[2*Pi*(9/5)*10^6*t], t, s])/((
     s^2 (-326427 + 2 s (870074 + 1024955 s)) - 
      32400000000000 \[Pi]^2 (339937 + s (2025061 + 1669570 s)))/(
     5 (12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 + s^2) (1046831 + 
        s (54823701 + 10 s (9477277 + 4110700 s)))))], 
  s -> 2*Pi*(9/5)*10^6*I]]
        
Out[4]=Sqrt[(1095855142561 + 
 12960000000000 \[Pi]^2 (2807216044153661 + 
    1296000000000000 \[Pi]^2 (44746021794589 + 
       218996194190400000000000000 \[Pi]^2)))/(1095855142561 + 
 38880000000000 \[Pi]^2 (53017054967887 + 
    669360190012848000000000000 \[Pi]^2))]/(360000 \[Pi])
        
In[5]:=N[%4]
        
Out[5]=33.0239
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond.  I'm new in this site. What I did, actually I need the amplification of a small signal, it works well, I check it on the scope. I also checked the operating point, that the DC collector voltage is about 1/2 of the supply voltage. Regarding the Input Impedance, it does not affect the signal source.  However I wonder if I can calculate the Input Impedance by only knowing the external component value and beta/DC current gain (this one I can measure). The data sheet of the BJT rarely have the h(hie, hfe, hre, hoe) parameters.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the long equation and solution of 415 ohms Input Impedance, but my original circuit the R3 is between Base and Collector.  In your simulation circuit R3 is connected the the junction of R7 & R8.

Comment: @MulaWWangsaputra I see, I will edit my answer when I've the time later today.

Comment: Thank you Jan, you’re so kind. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MulaWWangsaputra I've edited my answer. And you're totally welcome!

Comment: Thank you Jan, really appreciated.  Hmm, I'll study the detail, to my surprise the input impedance drastically reduce from 415 ohms to 33 ohms, Interesting

Comment: My mistake, I did not put units on the coupling and decoupling capacitor.  I meant 0.1 uF not 0.1 F, so R1, R5, R9 are 100000/s